# two teams (A and B ) play until one team has won 4 soccer games. What is the probability that team A wins for the 4th time on the 6th round

Tags: probability

what I think the answer is: First, I find the probability that B doesnt win 4 games in the first five rounds. This is $\frac{1}{2} ^ 4$ * $\frac{1}{2}$ * 5 + $\frac{1}{2} ^ 2$ * $\frac{1}{2} ^ 3$ * $\binom{5}{2}$ + $\frac{1}{2} ^ 3$ * $\frac{1}{2} ^ 2$ * $\binom{5}{3}$ because they can either win 1,2 or 3 games. Then, I multiply this by the probability that A wins exactly 3 games. This is $\frac{1}{2} ^ 3$ * $\frac{1}{2} ^ 2$ * $\binom{5}{3}$. Finally, I multiply this result by $\frac{1}{2}$ because the probability that A wins the 6th game is $\frac{1}{2}$. This comes to a final answer of $\frac{1}{1024}$. Would appreciate if someone could let me know if this approach is right. Thank you

Comment: Is it a given that $A$ and $B$ both have probability exactly $1/2$ to win any one game? Your answer assumes this but the question doesn't state it. Also, after five rounds, if $A$ must win exactly $3$ games, how many games, _exactly_, must $B$ win?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To generalise, we can take $A's$ winning probability for a round as $p$, losing probability as $q\,(=1-p)$, and since $A$ must win the $6th$ game and $3$ other preceding ones,

$Pr = [\binom53p^3q^2]p$

Answer (score 1):

The probability that $A$ wins the fourth time in the sixth round is the same as $A$ winning three of the first five and winning the sixth too.

So, assuming that the probabilities of each team winning is the same and there are no ties allowed, the probability is $\binom{5}{3}(\frac{1}{2})^3(\frac{1}{2})^2\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{10}{64}=\frac{5}{32}$.

However, if we are also accommodating ties, then the required probability is $\binom{5}{3}(\frac{1}{3})^3(\frac{2}{3})^2\times\frac{1}{3}=\frac{40}{729}$, assuming that the chances of either team and that of a team are the same.